# Is there a formula to check that every subsequent value in a vector is less than the previous (it's possible for equal values to exist)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to set a constraint in an optimization problem where each subsequent value is equal or less than the prior one.  Is there some sort of math trick to formulate this?  I've thought about some sort of product of differences that involves testing for negative values but the issue is that it's ok for the subsequent value to be the same.

I am hoping for a trick other than explicitly stating that each subsequent value must be less than the prior - as then my optimization problem is too complicated.

In other words, for a vector of n values, what's the least amount of tests I need to perform to ensure that the vector is in descending order?  And what are the tests I need?  Only operations allowed are addition, subtraction, power, multiplication or division.  No absolute values, if/then tests, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: I'd do $n-1$ tests for $a_1\ge a_2$, $a_2\ge a_3$, ..., $a_{n-1}\ge a_n$

Comment: Yeah I've been doing that, was wondering if there was a way to decrease the amount of tests.

Comment: In that case, you may need to define what you consider a test

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting your last paragraph, you seem to want to describe the set $$A=\{\,\mathbf a=(a_ß, a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\mid a_0\ge a_1\ge a_2\ge \ldots \ge a_n\,\}$$ as intersection of sets of the form
$$ C(f):=\{\,\mathbf a\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\mid f(\mathbf a)\ge 0\,\}$$
where $f$ is a polynomial in $n+1$ variables, and minimize the number of such sets used.
We also let
$$ V(f):=\{\,\mathbf a\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\mid f(\mathbf a)= 0\,\}$$
and note that the boundary of $C(f)$ is a subset of $V(f)$.

Equivalently, we can try to describe the more symmetric set
$$ B=\{\,\mathbf b=(b_1,\ldots,b_{n})\in\Bbb R^{n}\mid b_1\ge0, b_2\ge 0,\ldots, b_{n-1}\ge 0\,\}$$ as
such an intersection and note that $$(a_0,\ldots, a_n)\in A\iff (a_0-a_1,\ldots, a_{n-1}-a_n)\in B.$$
Redefine operators $C$ and $V$ accordingly for polynomials in $n$ variables.

Assume $$B=\bigcap _{i=1}^m C(f_i).$$
Write each $f_i$ as $\sum_{k\ge 0}f_{i,k}$ where $f_{i,k}$ is homogeneous of degree $k$, i.e., $f_{i,k}(\lambda\mathbf x)=\lambda^kf_{i,k}(\mathbf x)$.
If $d_i$ is the maximal degree for which such a summand is not identically zero, then $f_{i,d_i}$ dominates $f_i$ for large $\mathbf x$ and in a definable sense $C(f_i)$ tends to $C(f_{i,d_i})$  large $\mathbf x$. The act that $B$ itself is invariant under scaling with (positive) $\lambda$  then leads to the conclusion that we may assume that $f_i=f_{i,d_i}$, i.e., that wlog the $f_i$ are homogeneous.

The same argument applies to the restrictions of the $f_i$ to some hyperplane $x_1=1$, say. It follows that we may assume that $f_i(1,x_2,\ldots, x_{n})$ is homogeneous in $(x_2,\ldots, x_{n})$, hence also in $x_1$, and by symmetry in every single $x_k$. But then $f_i$ must be a single monomial!

For each $f_i$, let $S_i\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ be the set of indices $k$ such that $f_i$ is odd in $x_k$. Then we can replace $f_i$ with $\pm\prod_{k\in S_i}x_k$ without harm, i.e., for a suitable choice of $\epsilon_i\in\{-1,1\}$, we have
$$B=\bigcap_{i=1}^nC(\epsilon_i\prod_{k\in S_i}x_k ). $$
Consider the $2^{n}$ points $\mathbf x$ with $|x_k|=1$ for all $k$.
$B$ contains exactly one of these, $(1,\ldots,1)$. If we negate $\epsilon_i$ for all $i$ with $x_k\in S_i$, then the resulting intersection will again contain only one such point, namely the one with all entries $=+1$ except $x_k=-1$. By combining similar sign changes, we can adjust the signs $\epsilon_i$ in such a manner that the intersection contains any of our $2^n$ points (and no other). Therefore, we must be able to asign signs in at least $2^n$ ways to the $m$ monomials. In other words,
$$ m\ge n.$$